# how do you check two tables and only return the value from the table that matches in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as follows

Table 1

```
Name | Code
John | X11
Jane | CFT
Scot | KIT
```

Table 2

```
Name | Code
Kate | FX5
Jake | 1JI
Pete | GTS
```

what i want to achieve in one query is how do i check if i pass a code in it must check both the table and only returns the code that matches.
for example

```
    Select Name
    from Table 2 
    where Code='X11
```

there is no code with the above in table 2 so i have no results,but i do have it in the bellow

```
Select Name
from Table 1 
where Code='X11'
```

This will give me an output of john which i want.

How do i combine both of the queries just to check which code exists in which table then it must return the Name Value only from that table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
Select Name
from Table2 
where Code = 'X11'
union all
Select Name
from Table1 
where Code = 'X11';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try like following.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   table1 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   table2) t1 
WHERE  code = 'X11'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a result from only 1 of the 2 tables then you can use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
  (SELECT Name FROM Table1 WHERE Code='X11'),
  (SELECT Name FROM Table2 WHERE Code='X11')
  ) Name
```

This way if `'X11'` is found in the 1st table, the 2nd table will not be scanned.

Answer (score 1):

Sample Data

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE
    (Name   VARCHAR(100),
     Code VARCHAR(100)
    )
INSERT INTO  @Table1
SELECT 'John' , 'X11' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane' , 'CFT' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Scot' , 'KIT' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane' , 'TFT' 

DECLARE @Table2 AS TABLE
    (Name   VARCHAR(100),
     Code VARCHAR(100)
     )
 INSERT INTO  @Table2
 SELECT 'Kate' , 'FX5' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Jake' , 'X11' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Jane' , 'SER' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Pete' , 'KIT'
```

Sql code to obtain expected result using cross apply,this code used to find multiple codes those will be matched in both tables

```
SELECT t1_Name,
       t2_Name,
       Code
FROM
(
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN t.Code = a.Code THEN t.Name ELSE NULL END AS t1_Name,
    CASE WHEN t.Code = a.Code THEN a.Name ELSE NULL END AS t2_Name,
    t.Code AS Code,
    CASE WHEN t.Code = a.Code THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Flag
FROM @Table1 t
CROSS APPLY 
(
SELECT Name,Code FROM @Table2 t2
) AS a
)dt WHERE Flag = 1
```

Result

```
t1_Name  t2_Name    Code
*************************
John     Jake        X11
Scot     Pete        KIT
```